# jquery toggle text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
function toggle(div)
{

$("#"+div).toggle();
$("#l_detail").html('Hide');

}

<a href=""><label id="l_label>Details</label></a>
```

How to change text back to details in toglee function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function toggle(div) {  
 $("#"+div).toggle();

 var txt = $("#"+div).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Details';

 $("#l_detail").text(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull, if the toggle is animated, you cannot test the visibility of the div just after the "toggle" call. You should use the callback argument of the toggle function.

Example :

```
duration = 0; // Or whatever you want in ms
$("#"+div).toggle(duration,function(){
    var txt = $("#"+div).is(':visible') ? 'Details' : 'Changes';
    $("#l_detail").html(txt);
});
```

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: You can also set the txt variable prior to the toggle statement, then do the .html(txt) afterwards, so it won't matter how long the toggle takes or if it is done.  Of course, then the values you're choosing from for the variable txt would be in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the div is [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), and if it is `$("#l_detail").html('Hide')`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this (also shows off optional animation effect "slow"):

```
$("#"+div).click(function () {
    $("#l_detail").toggle("slow");
});
```

Pulled it from an example on the documentation site: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/